# Trying to put partial in different header

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following program working fine. But once I get rid of the forward declaration of the primary specialization in bar.h. I got compilation error saying the specialization is not a class template. Why?

```
bar.h:
template<typename T>
struct Bar{
    void bar()
    {
        std::cout<< "bar" << std::endl;
    };
};

//template<typename T> // Looks like I need to forward declare this in order to have it compile and work, why?
//struct IsBar;

template<typename T>
struct IsBar<Bar<T>> {
    static const bool value = true;
};

main.cpp:
#include "bar.h"

struct Raw{
};
template<typename T>
struct IsBar{
    static const bool value = false;
};

template<typename Obj, bool>
struct function{
    static void callbar(Obj obj){ 
        obj.bar();
    }; 
};

template<typename Obj>
struct function<Obj, false>{
    static void callbar(Obj obj){ 
        std::cout<< "no bar()" << std::endl;
    }; 
};

int main()
{
    typedef Bar<Raw> Obj;
    Obj obj;

    function<Obj, IsBar<Obj>::value> f;
    f.callbar(obj); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Before you can define a specialization, you need to at least declare the primary template. Otherwise there's nothing to specialize.

Comment: is this the same for full specialization?

Comment: Yes it is. You can try it and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because

```
template<typename T>
struct IsBar<Bar<T>> {
    static const bool value = true;
};
```

is a [template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates) of the template `IsBar<U>` for `U`=`Bar<T>`. In order to specialize a `template`, you must first declare the general un-specialized template.

Moreover, for this to work properly (for example in SFINAE), you want the general version to contain the `value=false`:

```
template<typename T>
struct IsBar
: std::integral_constant<bool,false>
{};

template<typename T>
struct IsBar<Bar<T>>
: std::integral_constant<bool,true>
{};
```

As this functionality is closely related to `struct Bar<>`, it should be defined within the same header file as `struct Bar<>`, i.e. bar.h in your case.